# PHP - Check if destination is writeable

Tags: php

I am trying to upload an image to a folder on the server using php, but i get this error message:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpPoVMRg' to 'userImages/Test/Test 2.jpg' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/TestSite/upload.php on line 16
Error uploading file - check destination is writeable.
```

It seems that something is preventing the upload. My guess is the operatingsystem but i am unsure how to allow writability then.

I use a mac with os x yosemite.

Here is also the upload code:

```
    <?php

session_start();

// Check for errors
if($_FILES['file_upload']['error'] > 0){
    die('An error ocurred when uploading.');
}

if(!getimagesize($_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'])){
    die('Please ensure you are uploading an image.');
}


// Upload file
if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'], 'userImages/Test/' . $_FILES['file_upload']['name'])){
    die('Error uploading file - check destination is writeable.');
}

die('File uploaded successfully.');


?>
```

Thank you for answers!

Comment: What permissions do you have set for that directory?

Comment: `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/TestSite/userImages/Test/` exists?

Comment: Well the folder was set on view only. But i changed it and it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Use is_writable function

```
if (is_writable($directory)) {
    echo 'I can write here';
} else {
    echo 'I can not write here';
}
```